# How bad is it to put rdlc files in layout folder

Tags: 2013

How bad is it to put rdlc files in layout folder ? I want to add it to layout folder so that in my webpart code behind I will be able to call it then.

I can't think of any other place, maybe custom database which is also not an issue for me as it's only an xml file.

Where you all folks keep your custom files when developing in SP farm solutions... keep in mind it's a multi-tenancy environment.